# How can Apple distribute Bash (and other GPL v2 software) with macOS? Is it not a derivative work?

Tags: licensing, gpl-2, copyleft

And how could they license Darwin as APSL if based on GPL v2 software?
[See](https://github.com/apple-oss-distributions/bash/blob/9817a9670495eb01c195f7f24e459db192c5111d/bash-3.2/COPYING)

Comment: The title and the text of your question do not match. Your question asks about Darwin, which is based on the Mach kernel along with features from FreeBSD. Neither of these are GPL licensed. Bash is a separate program distributed alongside the OS.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the GPL v2:

> In addition, mere aggregation of another work not based on the Program with the Program (or with a work based on the Program) on a volume of a storage or distribution medium does not bring the other work under the scope of this License.

See also the ["Mere Aggregation"](https://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-faq.en.html#MereAggregation) entry in the GPL FAQ and the [Using copyleft software (GPL v2) and distribute it with proprietary software](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/12803/using-copyleft-software-gpl-v2-and-distribute-it-with-proprietary-software) question here.